# PHP performing logical AND of two arrays

Tags: php

I have two arrays with exactly the same key names but different binary values. I would like to form an array containing the logical AND of the binary values in each array.

eg:

```
$array1 = Array ([Ant] => 1 [Arm] => 1 [Ash] => 1 [AUB] => 0 [Bas] => 1 [Bay] );

$array2 = Array ([Ant] => 1 [Arm] => 0 [Ash] => 1 [AUB] => 1 [Bas] => 1 [Bay] );

$finalArray = ($array1 AND $array2);
```

//The expected output is:

```
$finalArray = Array ([Ant] => 1 [Arm] => 0 [Ash] => 1 [AUB] => 0 [Bas] => 1 [Bay] );
```

Comment: `foreach` & (pun intended) `&` are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array_walk function

```
array_walk($array1, function(&$value, $key) use ($array2) {
    $value = $array2[$key] && $value;
});
```

The $array1 will have the final value